# Wordpress category.php Pagination 404 Errors

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404, categories

I'm trying to display posts for categories in my category.php file with pagination, but when I click the "older posts" button, I'm getting a 404. Here's the code I'm currently using for the query:

```
<?php

    // Get ID of category we're currently looking at
    $cat = get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) );

    query_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'=>25,
        'cat' => $cat,
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
    ));
    if(have_posts()):
?>
```

The permalink structure I'm using is /%category%/%postname%/

I've read that there is a bug that will leave you with a 404 error if the "posts_per_page" is set to less than the default, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. The default in my settings is 20.

Any ideas? Is this an issue with the permalink settings? Shouldn't having /category-name/page/2 work the same way as /blog-page/page/2 works?

I also get a 404 if I try to access categories like this: /category/cat-name, or /blog-page/category/cat-name

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

This sounds very similar to what I experienced (In my child theme, custom permalink %category%%postname% resulted in a 404 when using pagination in category.php, only on page 2 though).

I found this solution worked really well: http://www.bamboosolutions.co.uk/fix-404-errors-wordpress-pagination/

To summarize the solution, in my child `functions.php` file I added this bit of code:

```
function custom_pre_get_posts( $query ) {  
if( $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && is_category()) {  
    $query->set( 'paged', str_replace( '/', '', get_query_var( 'page' ) ) );  }  } 

add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_pre_get_posts'); 

function custom_request($query_string ) { 
     if( isset( $query_string['page'] ) ) { 
         if( ''!=$query_string['page'] ) { 
             if( isset( $query_string['name'] ) ) { unset( $query_string['name'] ); } } } return $query_string; } 

add_filter('request', 'custom_request');
```

I spent so much time reading about different causes and solutions for this error, in my case it was that WP was not requesting the correct custom category. This fix saved a lot of my time!

Comment: After I managed to the get the pagination going for the category this issue came up. With your answer I got it all working just fine, thank you!

Comment: That worked for the 404. Now www.domain.com/taxonomy/page/2 does not show 404 BUT it only loads the first pages content each time.

Comment: yes! thank you... the script combined with the `query_posts ` in the original answer worked for me

Comment: There is a plugin that implements this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-pagination-fix/

Comment: Thank you!! (One typo: change `is_category()` to `&& is_category()`.) Thank heavens for StackOverflow! I thought I was going to spend HOURS troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and Lauren's fix helped me. My problem was that with this code the current page didn't change, it got stuck on page 1.

In functions.php i added the following code:

```
function custom_pre_get_posts($query)
{
    if ($query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && is_category()) {
        $query->set('page_val', get_query_var('paged'));
        $query->set('paged', 0);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```

and in category template (category.php) i used this code:

```
  $paged = (get_query_var('page_val') ? get_query_var('page_val') : 1);
  $query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'cat' => $cat,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'DESC'));
```

for pagination i changed this code like this. Hope my solution helps:

```
$big = 999999999;  
echo paginate_links(array(
                        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                        'format' => '/page/%#%',
                        'current' => max(1, $paged),
                        'prev_text' => __('Previous Page'),
                        'next_text' => __('Next Page'),
                        'show_all' => true,
                        'total' => $query->max_num_pages
                    ));
```

Comment: This does solve 404 problems also. Thanks for posting this. I was having an issue that /category/news/page/2 showing 404. This solution fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try switching to WP_Query first, it's less buggy with Pagination.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

> query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

```
$cat = get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) );
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$the_query = new  WP_Query
 (
          array
          (
              'posts_per_page'=>25,
              'cat' => $cat,
              'paged' => $paged
          ),
);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
```

If that doesn't work, try changing your permalink structure to Post ID and see if that changes it.
If neither of those work, set $cat to a category you know exists (and has 26 posts) and make sure that's not causing the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works if I change the permalink structure from `/%category%/%postname%` to `/%category%/%post_id%`. But that's not really a feasible option. I need the post title in the URLs for SEO purposes.

Comment: It works when I change a link from `/%category%/page/2/` to `/category/%category%/page/2/`. However, the wordpress functions that add the older/newer posts links don't have that in their URLs.

Comment: You could try this https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/category-pagination-fix it hasn't been updated in 2 years, but theres a review post from last month saying it still works. (it's just two small functions.) Hopefully this can help you solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! That partially worked. I had to change a couple of things in the plugin to get it to work. The code is here for anyone who might need it: http://creative.link/code/wordpress-category-pagination-fix/